# How to make columns import data from columns in .xls

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that imports from .xls files. I added some columns to the `DataTable` by using `DataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName");`.

What I want to do now is that column "ColumnName" to import the data from column `F1` in a .xls.
Previously I tried to add the columns by using the `<` sign in the datagrid but I could not reference to the column name.